# SVG/TopoJSON for world map with US states

Tags: dictionary, svg, d3.js, topojson

I'm using D3 to create a Choropleth map of the world. I need an SVG or TopoJSON file that shows a map of the world at country level but with state outlines for the US. The only ones I've found are outdated files from Wikimedia Commons that are too large (from 1998 and ~18MB, see below).

Can anyone point me to where I might find a more recent (and smaller) file?

Thanks!

OUTDATED / TOO LARGE

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World98.svg
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World98%2B.svg

Comment: have you thought about finding a shapefile and using ogr2ogr and topojson in the command line to convert from shapefile to topojson?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to find a shapefile and use ogr2ogr and topojson to convert from shape to topojson, try:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-50m.json

which is taken from:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3946824

*edit:

I just realized you need the states outlined in the US. As such, your best bet is to find a world shapefile and a us-state shapefile and use ogr2ogr to convert from shape to json like:

```
ogr2ogr -f geoJSON worldout.json worldin.shp
```

Then use topojson to convert and combine geoJSON:

```
topojson -o combinedout.json  -- woldout.json statesout.json
```